# How to select ALL usernames from my members table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to select and display all the usernames stored in the members table in my MySQL database.

This is my current code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM members");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $row['username'];
```

This only lists one username though.

How would I go about getting and listing all usernames?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use `fetchAll()` in a loop http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php which I will NOT be posting an answer for ;-) because it's already been answered *here*.

Comment: If you do not have any parameters, then do not use prepared statements, they are just a waste of resources in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM members");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In essence, once you execute the query,  you have to loop the array where all the rows are stored.  So feel free to use any of the control functions that PHP offers.

I use this approach:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM members");
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $row)
  {
    echo $row[0];
  }
```

In my case, I define all fetching options in the function that defines and instantiates the DataBase connection,  using PDO.